# opendkim Permission Denied when loading the key

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, dkim, postfix-mta

I have installed opendkim to my Ubuntu server 14.04.4 LTS. I have set into the postfix config to be used the opendkim previous created mail.private key.

When I try to send a mail I see the following messages into the /var/log/mai.log file

```
Jan 29 09:19:47 test postfix/smtpd[2427]: connect from ip6localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jan 29 09:19:47 test postfix/smtpd[2427]: 625E3E0FE7: client=ip6-localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jan 29 09:19:47 test postfix/cleanup[2431]: 625E3E0FE7: message-id=<890ba29cd6ef289c50581335723ccdb9[edited domain]>
Jan 29 09:19:47 test opendkim[1370]: can't load key from /etc/opendkim/keys/mail.private: Permission denied
Jan 29 09:19:47 test opendkim[1370]: 625E3E0FE7: error loading key 'mail._[edited domain]'
```

The key was stored into the folder /etc/opendkim/keys

```
root@test:/home/crewlog.com# ls -l /etc/opendkim
total 16
drw------- 2 opendkim opendkim 4096 Jan 29 07:49 keys
-rw-r----- 1 opendkim opendkim  891 Jan 29 07:48 mail.private
-rw------- 1 opendkim opendkim   67 Jan 29 08:01 KeyTable
-rw------- 1 opendkim opendkim   32 Jan 29 07:47 SigningTable
-rw------- 1 opendkim opendkim   81 Jan 29 07:19 TrustedHosts
```

I used the opendkim:opendkim user. Here is my /etc/opendkim.config file

```
AutoRestart             Yes
AutoRestartRate         10/1h
Syslog                  yes
UMask                   002
SyslogSuccess           Yes
LogWhy                  Yes
Canonicalization        relaxed/simple
PidFile                 /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid
SignatureAlgorithm      rsa-sha256
ExternalIgnoreList      refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
InternalHosts           refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
KeyTable                refile:/etc/opendkim/KeyTable
SigningTable            refile:/etc/opendkim/SigningTable
UserID opendkim:opendkim
Mode                    sv
OversignHeaders         From
Domain                  [edited domain]
KeyFile                 /etc/opendkim/keys/mail.private
Selector                mail
SOCKET                  inet:8891@127.0.0.1
```

Any help will be welcomed as I don't know what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the mail.private in the wrong directory, it's looking in the keys directory for mail.private.
Move mail.private into the keys directory and make sure opendkim has permission to read the file.